# visual studio code setting of IntelliSense

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, when I enter a code and complete it with that suggested part, it does not show me the parentheses, for example, when I type the print command, it does not show the parentheses, how should I fix it?

Comment: because you do not always want the `()`, python is a high level language, functions can be arguments to a function

Comment: then create your own snippets with `()`, like `mprint` for `print($1)$0`

Comment: Welcome! As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following codes to your `settings.json` and reload VSCode:

```
"python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true
```