# Quick suggestion doesn't come with brackets in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, brackets, autosuggest

When I write the code, the hint will show up and I just have to press enter. For example when type print and enter I will get print(). But after updating vscode there is no more () ? people got ocd like me are uncomfortable :(

I want to bring my brackets again

Comment: You may need to update the Python VS Code extension as well

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76451602/9938317), within 24h 2 times the same question, do users search before asking

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to achieve this effect?

[image]

Add the following configuration to *settings.json*:

```json
    "python.analysis.completeFunctionParens": true,
```

Or search for `python.analysis.completeFunctionParens` in **Settings** and check it

[image]

Explanation of this setting

> Add parentheses to function completions.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to settings then type in `bracket` in the search bar. This may provide you with a way to turn them back on. Not sure though I looked and couldn't find something obvious.